# How to find out which jars containing in spring boot starter web dependency

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I wanted to know what are available jars in dependency and how to find it,
Please help me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check in IDE like STS and IntelliJ, in Project Structure > external libraries. You'll find all the jars which are included in the project.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I have one more query that how can I remove a specific jar alone from my build path is there a way?

Comment: you can use <exclude> tag to do so

Answer (score 0):

If your project is maven based project :

`mvn dependency:tree`

For convenience write the result into a file so that you can inspect it easier:

`mvn dependency:tree > result.txt`